# NotifyItemChanged gets called in OnResume() but doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I am trying to update an area in the `RecyclerView` after a setting has been changed. It only has to the text of one index and I don't want to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` since it will take too much resources just to update one index. The `onResume()` function gets called but if I try to call `notifyItemChanged()`, it doesn't work. What did I do wrong here? Thank you.

OnActivityCreated:

```
 private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
 private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
 private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        viewAdapter = ListAdapter(mylist)
recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview).apply {
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                layoutManager = viewManager
                adapter=ListAdapter(devicelist).apply {
}
```

OnResume:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val position = list[pos.toInt()]  //position gotten from Viewmodel
    viewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position.pos!!) 
    //position.pos is Int? but it needs Int so I added !! in the end.
}
```

Comment: try using observer on viewModel instead, notifyItemChanged() is capable of handling changes to items within the list. I don't see any reason why You need to call that on OnResume()

Comment: @PankajNimgade I don't get what you mean. Can you please explain? Thanks. Also, I called that on OnResume() because I have a settings page wherein you can edit the name of that object being displayed. When it goes back to the MainActivity, the name has to refresh.